# The Interchanging of Limits

Tags: limits

Suppose we have two examples of nested limits, in this case:

$Limit$ $1$$:$ $\lim_{n\to +\infty}$ $($ $\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}$ $x^n$ $)$

$Limit$ $2$$:$ $\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}$ $($ $\lim_{n\to +\infty}$ $x^n$ $)$

I know that the value of Limit 1 is equal to 1, and the value of Limit 2 is equal to 0. However, I don't understand why, in this case, the interchanging of limits changes the value of the nested limit; any elaboration?

Comment: Instead of asking why you can't interchange limits in *this* case, I think you would be better served by asking when it is okay to interchange limits.

Comment: My question is more to do with these limits specifically; because I am unsure of how these limits were evaluated differently and why they're different. Any specific conditions I'm not asking about, but I believe the condition is both the limit function and the function that is having its limit taken (in this case x^n) are both continuous. My question is more to do with this specific question though, and the differing logic for why the first Limit is 1 and the second limit is 0